# Nesting If Statements in Java

Tags: java, python, if-statement

I am having trouble nesting these if statements from Python to Java.

```
 def leapyear(yearr):
   if (year % 4 == 0):
       if (year % 100 == 0):
          if (year % 400 == 0):
               return True
           else:
               return False
       else:
           return True
   else:
       return False
```

I currently am working to convert the above to Java:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)   {
    if (year % 4==0) {
        if (yearr%100==0) {
           if (year%400==0) {
    else 
        return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, my Java conversion is giving me errors, mainly because I do not think my nested conditionals have the right closed braces. Can you give me any hints or resources that can help me figure this out?

Comment: A one liner: `return year%4 == 0 && (year%400 == 0 || year%100 != 0)`

Answer (score 4):

Your `else` statements need braces too, you forgot a `return` statement for the innermost `if`, and you misspelled `yearr` in one location:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)   {
    if (year % 4==0) {
        if (year % 100 == 0) {
           if (year % 400 == 0) {
               return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Java doesn't need the indentation like Python does, but it'd help make your branching structure more readable if you did use it anyway:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)   {
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        if (year % 100 == 0) {
           if (year % 400 == 0) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You don't need as many `return` statements here, the `year % 400 == 0` already evaluates to a boolean:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)   {
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        if (year % 100 == 0) {
            return year % 400 == 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or as a one-liner:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)   {
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

For completeness sake, here is the Python version the way *I* would write it:

```
def leapyear(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

or better still, use [`calendar.isleap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap) instead.

Comment: and this would be much more readable if it was indented correctly (as it was in Python) :-)

Comment: you forgot the closing braces for the ifs

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: which tells you how much of a Python dev I am; my braces foo is rusty.

Comment: Are you positive you would write it that way in Python? Quite apart from the pirate rr:  `import calendar` `calendar.isleap(yearr)`

Comment: @Duncan: I was rewriting the logic of original function; I'd use `calendar.isleap(year)` too, yes. :-P

Comment: @Duncan: but, replaced it with a one-liner. You are right, that's what I'd do in the end if there wasn't a `calendar.isleap()` function.

Answer (score 4):

It's not good practice to have so many possible exit points. Also, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can use Java library code, for example:

```
boolean isLeapYear(int year){
  GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
  return cal.isLeapYear(year); 
}
```

Comment: See [Where did the notion of "one return only" come from?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118703); it's fine to use multiple exit points in Java and other languages with automated resource management. It's still much better to use the standard library and not reinvent the wheel, of course.

Answer (score 1):

heres my attempt:

```
boolean leapyear(int year)
{
  if (year % 4 == 0)
  {
      if (year % 100 == 0)
      {
        return (year % 400 == 0);
      }
      else
      {
          return true
      }
  }

  return false;
}
```

or use this:

```
return Java.util.GregorianCalendar.getInstance().isLeapYear(year)
```

Comment: Does Java have a DateTime.IsLeapYear() method? My Google-fu only turns up that method for dotNet.

Comment: If you want to put it back in, it seems what you meant to say was that the if statements could be replaced by `return Java.util.GregorianCalendar.getInstance().isLeapYear(year)`

Answer (score 1):

What about removing the ifs altogether?

```
public boolean leapyear(int year) {
    return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    boolean leapyear(int year)   
{
    if (year % 4==0) 
    {
        if (year%100==0) 
        {
           if (year%400==0)
           {
            return true;
           }
           else
           { 
              return true;
           }
       }
       else``
       {
        return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing an `else` and `return` somewhere.

Comment: the condition year%400 returns always true